# UIWebView not loading all pages of Google sign-in

Tags: ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, feedly

I'm building an iOS app with Feedly Authentication in it. This choice wasn't made by me, but I was tasked with building this. So I set up the `UIViewController` below with a `UIWebView` in it. This webview loads the Feedly authentication page. However, after I press Google. And type in my credentials, the webview doesn't load anything. Even after clicking submit multiple times, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Could it be the `localhost` as `redirect_uri`?

**LoginWebViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginWebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

**LoginWebViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginWebViewController.h"

@interface LoginWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginWebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
    toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

    #define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
    colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
    green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
    blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

    // choose whatever width you need instead of 600
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-40, 0, 80, 25)];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.shadowColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xe5e7eb);
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    label.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x717880);
    label.text = @"Log in";
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    UIBarButtonItem *toolBarTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                              action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];

    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneButton, spacer, toolBarTitle, spacer, nil];

    [toolbar setItems:items];

    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 24, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-24)];
    webview.delegate = self;
    NSString *url=@"https://sandbox.feedly.com/v3/auth/auth/?response_type=code&client_id=sandbox&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSString *myRequestedUrl= [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"Requested url: %@", myRequestedUrl);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSString *myLoadedUrl = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"Loaded url: %@", myLoadedUrl);
}

@end
```

Comment: It is working fine after entering my credentials & pressing on sign in button for Google it is showing me "feedly would like to access page.....". Try on Device or with other google account

Comment: Yeah, but if you click 'accept' for "feedly would like to access page.....", nothing happens...

Comment: I think you are not only one see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657011/feedly-google-authentication-not-working , might be their may be problem in google authentication .

Comment: That's actually my question. I didn't remember that I already posted it, stupid as it sounds.